# Repeatedly update contents of a list box while maintaining user control

Tags: vba, wait, text-files, listbox-control

In VBA, I am repeatedly updating the contents of a list box with the text of a steadily growing text file. Is there any way to let the user maintain control (scroll the list box, press a button) while the loop that I'm in to update the list box is running? 
An alternative to application.wait would also work; as in, update -> wait x seconds (where the user can still do stuff -> update again -> repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a start.  In a regular module, paste this code:

```
Sub ShowUserForm()
UserForm1.Show vbModeless
End Sub

Sub UpdateTextBox()
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
With UserForm1.ListBox1
    .List = ws.Range("A1:A" & ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value2
    .ListIndex = .ListCount - 1
End With
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:5"), "UpdateTextBox"
End Sub
```

In your userform paste this code in the UserForm_Activate event:

```
UpdateTextBox
```

It updates the values from column A of Sheet1 in the workbook with the code.

To test it, run ShowUserForm.

Comment: That actually works great! Is there any way to make it automatically scroll to the bottom of whatever has been added, or to automatically select the bottom line? Whenever it updates, it jumps to whatever line is selected and sets it as the bottom text (or as close to the bottom as it can make it,) and the default selection is the top line, so every time it updates, it jumps back up to the top.

Comment: I added a line to the code that selects the last line in the listbox.