# VBA Refresh UserForm ListBox Data when source changes

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

Hi I have encountered problem with my listbox data in my Userform
When I try to change the source file where my listbox connected it doesn't seems to change

It was showing good data at first but when I try to click RUN DATE button

[image]

It doesn't go with the Value in my Range that is being set as My key for sorting

[image]

Here is my code for RUN DATE BUTTON for sorting Ascending and Descending

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Application.EnableEvents = False

Worksheets("combobox_value").Activate
Dim strDataRange As Range
Dim keyRange As Range
Set strDataRange = Range("I2:L4")
Set keyRange = Range("I2:I4")

If Range("M2").Value = "D" Then

strDataRange.Sort Key1:=keyRange, Order1:=xlDescending
Range("M2").Value = "A"
Else
strDataRange.Sort Key1:=keyRange, Order1:=xlAscending
Range("M2").Value = "D"
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

And this is how I initialize the value in my listbox

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
'set ListBox properties on initialization of UserForm
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("combobox_value")
lastRow_combobox_column = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row


With ListBox1
.ColumnCount = 4
.ColumnWidths = "100"
.ColumnHeads = False
.ControlTipText = True
End With

'Load Worksheet Range directly to a ListBox:
Dim var As Variant


var = Sheets("combobox_value").Range("I2:L" & lastRow_combobox_column)


Me.ListBox1.List = var


End Sub
```

Is there a way to refresh my listbox? Listbox1.refresh something like that?

Note: I don't need to close my Userform and open again to see the updated listbox
so while the Userform is in active mode(Open) I can directly update the listbox value..

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Repeatedly update contents of a list box while maintaining user control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8807070/repeatedly-update-contents-of-a-list-box-while-maintaining-user-control)

Comment: I look at the post but problem is I will not close my Userform while updating my ListBox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using var and assigning the data to `List` from `var`, you can use `Named Range` of data in the sheet and assign the property
  `ListBox1.RowSource = "Name of the Range"`

Every time you want to refresh the `listbox` just use the above assignment in your code and it will work. If you find any difficulty please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a refresh procedure, then call it in your OnClick event procedure for the button. 
Note, I haven't tested this code, but it should do what your original question asked.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    'set ListBox properties on initialization of UserForm
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("combobox_value")
    lastRow_combobox_column = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row

    With ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = 4
        .ColumnWidths = "100"
        .ColumnHeads = False
        .ControlTipText = True
    End With

    RefreshListbox 
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()    
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Worksheets("combobox_value").Activate
    Dim strDataRange As Range
    Dim keyRange As Range
    Set strDataRange = Range("I2:L4")
    Set keyRange = Range("I2:I4")

    If Range("M2").Value = "D" Then

        strDataRange.Sort Key1:=keyRange, Order1:=xlDescending
        Range("M2").Value = "A"
    Else
        strDataRange.Sort Key1:=keyRange, Order1:=xlAscending
        Range("M2").Value = "D"
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    RefreshListbox
End Sub

Private Sub RefreshListbox()
    Me.ListBox1.Clear
    'Load Worksheet Range directly to a ListBox:
    Dim ListRange As Range
    ListRange = Sheets("combobox_value").Range("I2:L" & lastRow_combobox_column)
    Me.ListBox1.List = ListRange
End Sub
```

Comment: I didn't have your source form to test with, and I've been working with Excel Interop in .Net lately, so I can't remember if you need to repaint the form to show the updated listbox.  If it doesn't show the updates, add a line at the end of the RefreshListBox procedure: `Me.Repaint`