# Excel Listbox not updating after ListFillRange change

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

So I was trying to create a dynamic Listbox, and everything works except the listbox doesn't update. If you look in properties the ListFillRange has changed, but the actual box keeps the same range.

My code is as follow:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()

Dim Rng As String

Rng = "'Identificatie_&_WGK'!R2:R" & (Worksheets("Identificatie_&_WGK").Range("S2").Value + 1)

Worksheets("Etiketten").ListBox1.ListFillRange = Rng

End Sub
```

The S2 is the amount of names it needs to display.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31363607/vba-refresh-userform-listbox-data-when-source-changes