# Updating the data in the list in real time in excel using VBA

Tags: excel

I have a Listbox that displays the data present in the rows of a table in excel. If some contents of the table are updated while running the script, the update only gets reflected in the Listbox if I run it again. How to reflect the changes in real-time?

My script is below. Kindly suggest modifications

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DataStorage")
Dim i As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Me.ListBox1.Clear

For i = 2 To Application.CountA(sh.Range("BP:BP"))
    Me.ListBox1.AddItem sh.Cells(i, 68).Value
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: At least 2 different suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31363607/3654325

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBA Refresh UserForm ListBox Data when source changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31363607/vba-refresh-userform-listbox-data-when-source-changes)